# How can I create an AWS Kinesis Firehose connected to S3 using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to use the `kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream` resource to create a Kinesis Firehose with a `Direct PUT` source, no data transformation, and an `extended_s3` destination.

I've modified the code in [this example](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream#extended-s3-destination) (to remove the lambda function) so now it looks like this:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "test-kinesis-destination-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "kinesis_event_stream" {
  name        = "kinesis-test-stream"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
    buffer_size = 1
    buffer_interval = 60
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "firehose_role" {
  name = "firehose_test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}
```

Terraform is able to successfully apply everything but Firehose doesn't seem to be able to write to S3.

Am I missing something in my IAM role? and if so how can I fix it?

### Edit

I've updated my terraform file to update the IAM policy, per @Marcin 's answer, to give Firehose permission to write to S3.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "bucket" {
  bucket = "test-kinesis-destination-bucket"
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "kinesis_event_stream" {
  name        = "kinesis-test-stream"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn   = aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn = aws_s3_bucket.bucket.arn
    buffer_size = 1
    buffer_interval = 60
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "firehose_role" {
  name = "firehose_test_role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",  
  "Statement":
  [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF

  inline_policy {
    name = "kinesis-s3-inline-policy"
    policy = jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {      
          Effect = "Allow",      
          Action = [
            "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
            "s3:PutObject"
          ]      
          Resource = [        
            "arn:aws:s3:::test-kinesis-destination-bucket",
            "arn:aws:s3:::test-kinesis-destination-bucket/*"            
          ]    
        },
        {
          Effect = "Allow"
          Action = [
            "kinesis:DescribeStream",
            "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
            "kinesis:GetRecords",
            "kinesis:ListShards"
          ]
          Resource = aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_event_stream.arn
        }
      ]
    })
  }
}
```

But when I run `terraform plan` I get the following error:

```sh
$ terraform plan
╷
│ Error: Cycle: aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_event_stream, aws_iam_role.firehose_role
│ 
│ 
|
```

How can I reference Firehose's ARN inside its IAM policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have created role `firehose_role` with only trust relatinship, but **no actual S3 permissions**. Your role should have the following permissions as explained in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/controlling-access.html#using-iam-s3) (you can trim it down if you don't use lambda with kinesis, kms or other services that firehose can use):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",  
    "Statement":
    [    
        {      
            "Effect": "Allow",      
            "Action": [
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],      
            "Resource": [        
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*"            
            ]    
        },        
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kinesis:DescribeStream",
                "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
                "kinesis:GetRecords",
                "kinesis:ListShards"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:region:account-id:stream/stream-name"
        },
        {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "kms:Decrypt",
               "kms:GenerateDataKey"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:kms:region:account-id:key/key-id"           
           ],
           "Condition": {
               "StringEquals": {
                   "kms:ViaService": "s3.region.amazonaws.com"
               },
               "StringLike": {
                   "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:s3:arn": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/prefix*"
               }
           }
        },
        {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "logs:PutLogEvents"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:logs:region:account-id:log-group:log-group-name:log-stream:log-stream-name"
           ]
        },
        {
           "Effect": "Allow", 
           "Action": [
               "lambda:InvokeFunction", 
               "lambda:GetFunctionConfiguration" 
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:lambda:region:account-id:function:function-name:function-version"
           ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I reference Kinesis's ARN in my policy? When I try to use `Resource = aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_event_stream.arn` I get a cycle error.

Comment: @APoor Can you update the code with its new version and the new error? Or alternatively, make a new question?

Comment: I've updated my question with the new code/error

Comment: @APoor You need to manually construct the arn, as your kinesis resource does not exist yet.

Answer (score 4):

@A Poor:
`But when I run terraform plan I get the following error:`

You are in loop:

- `aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream` is wating `aws_iam_role` to get `aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn`
- `aws_iam_role`  is waiting: `aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream` to get `aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_event_stream.arn`

So I use: `"Resource": "arn:aws:kinesis:ap-southeast-1:${var.account_id}:stream/${var.kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream_name}"`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the `cycle` terraform is complaining about, you can convert your `inline_policy` into a `aws_iam_role_policy` instead.

With this approach, you can reference the `aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_event_stream.arn` without the `cycle` error.

For example

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "firehose_role" {
  name = "${local.service}-${var.environment}-kinesis-firehose-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement":
  [
    {
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "firehose.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "firehose_role_policy" {
  name = "${local.service}-${var.environment}-kinesis-firehose-inline-policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.firehose_role.id
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        Effect = "Allow",
        Action = [
          "s3:AbortMultipartUpload",
          "s3:GetBucketLocation",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
          "s3:PutObject"
        ]
        Resource = [
          "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}",
          "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.bucket.id}/*"
        ]
      },
      {
        Effect = "Allow"
        Action = [
          "kinesis:DescribeStream",
          "kinesis:GetShardIterator",
          "kinesis:GetRecords",
          "kinesis:ListShards"
        ]
        Resource = aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_event_stream.arn
      }
    ]
  })
}
```

ref

- [Difference between aws_iam_policy and aws_iam_role_policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66510222/difference-between-aws-iam-policy-and-aws-iam-role-policy)